# Ubuntu Server 18.04 and 20.04 fail on 2010 PC

Tags: 18.04, server, 20.04, system-installation, hard-drive

At the moment I am trying to install Ubuntu Server on a PC made in 2010 (this is not the first time I have made a server on old hardware), however when I attempt to install Ubuntu Server 18.04 the installer will report "Unable to install Ubuntu Server 18.04, please try again..." or something of the like. Trying the 'mini.iso' version of the Ubuntu Server 18.04 the installer freezes after pressing install. Trying Ubuntu Server 20.04 the installer makes it further but eventually does the same as the first instance, however the only difference between 18.04 and 20.04 is that before 20.04's installer launches it reports three times 'blk_update_request: I/O error, dev fd0, sector 0', it then continues as normal. Does this have anything to do with the failed attemps? Some extra info, I have two identical 500GB harddrives and a similar 250GB harddrive, I'm attempting to run the two 500GB hdds in a RAID0 config and then have the 250GB drive for Ubuntu Server itself to install on. Thanks...

Comment: Did you verify the ISO before writing to install media? and validate the write to your installation media?  The message about `fd0` means nothing but your BIOS is reporting a floppy drive is *enabled* which doesn't contain a floppy-disk (thus can be ignored)

Comment: @guiverc I have not verified the ISO, I will look into how to do that now... Using the USB now, I get repeated errors saying things like `ata1.00: exception Emask 0x0 SAct 0x0 SErr 0x0 action 0x6 frozen ` and other things that decided to disappear now, its booting as usual now... `Failed unmounting /cdrom`... All those blk_update_request... And now back to how it was before... And I have no clue how on earth I get the md5sum for Ubuntu Server 20.04... Just gonna download 20.10 and see if that fixes anything...

Comment: And 20.10 just gives me `GRUB loading. Welcome to GRUB! error symbol 'grub_calloc' not found. Entering Rescue mode...`

Answer (score 0):

Just used my trusty laptop and a USB HD dock to install it that way... Thanks for all your help...